# Is it appropriate in a developer's job description to have "error free" as a key output?

Tags: terminology

As part of a review of all job descriptions, my company has decided to include the following as a key output:

> website development completed on
>   time, within specification and **error
>   free**

Given that specifications regularly change, there is no formal change control process and environments are, shall we say, a little unpredictable, how realistic and reasonable is this KPI?

Comment: Completely unrealistic. That was probably written by someone who's worked with one too many bad developers. But it could also be the fault of bad management. Not enough information provided.

Comment: The developer who comes in with "writes error free code" on their resume will be ludicrous enough to match the position.

Comment: The only code that can be proven to not have any bugs and achieve it's goal is an empty code base that claims to do nothing.

Comment: @unholysampler: So, how much for your 100% bug-free API? :P

Comment: pfft... looks like a scapegoat clause to can people easily. "Sorry, you didn't live up to your employment agreement... we're going to fire you without notice or additional cause. Tootles."

Comment: @SnOrfus: I wonder how well that would hold up in court...

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: You're probably right, but my experience has taught me that most companies don't have the critical thinking or research skills necessary to know that it wouldn't. Either that or they're betting that the employee won't go through the hassle and potential expense of fighting it.

Comment: The final scapegoat clause is the last agreement: "Both parties acknowledge that this job description is general in nature and may be varied by the employer, after consultation , as business needs require."

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: You'd be surprised. @S.Lott claims to write "error-free code". http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/65294/attachment-to-code/65308#65308

Comment: Of course it's error free. The compiler says: 0 errors, 0 warnings. That completely fulfills the job requirements :-)

Comment: @unholysampler: Yes, it looks like the developers are going to be constrained to writing "Hello World" programs.

Comment: @Jim G: Precisely, he claims to have written code that has not _yet_ encountered an error :)

Comment: @Phil.Wheeler Sounds like a very unattractive job posting full of nebulous pseudo-law-speak and impossible demands. Have you tried letting a human write one instead?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"Error Free" is **far too subjective**.  One man's "Unfufilled feature request" is another man's "Error".  Something like "Should substantially meet design specs" would be more appropriate.  I've never actually seen what you describe in a job description.  I've seen it for *contract work*, but not for employees.

Answer (score 9):

I'll take an opposing position to most answers and say it's absolutely reasonable and realistic.

Will all development be completed on time? Of course it won't, not always.

Will all development be completed within specification? You'd like to hope so, but sometimes that will simply not be possible and you'll have to flag a deviation from an impossible or self-contradictory spec.

And will all development be error free? **Never**.

But that's what a KPI is for. It's something that can be measured and by which you can track performance and progress.

If specifications regularly change, there is no formal change control process and environments are unpredictable, then it will be a challenge to keep this figure close to "error free". But that challenge is **your job**, and it's a job which you will hopefully do quite well - and even better next year, as you get more practice at managing your company's own particular flavour of chaos.

Counter question: what KPIs would *you* propose for a programmer? It's a tough one. A lot of what we do is hard to measure.

Comment: A code base of any significant size is practically impossible to guarantee as "error free", because there could be an error that you simply haven't found. Also, what's an error? A bug? How is this measured?

Comment: @philosodad - that's kinda my point. **It will not be error free**. But if this year *x* errors are found in code you wrote, and next year *x-4* are, you've improved on your KPI. As to what an error is, that's really a matter for your organization, and no doubt one that will cause some arguments re "error" vs. "undocumented requirement" vs. "changed requirement" vs. "difference of opinion".

Comment: Well I believe it’s unreasonable, however I see your point regarding KPIs. I've had a KPI which stated my code must be error free in production. Which meant I've done everything reasonable to provide error free code. After passing test my code would be released. This was fair enough.

Comment: @Carson63000: but that's my point! A KPI that is guaranteed to cause several arguments, lead to inevitable disagreements among parties, and vaguely defines a key metric is, at the very least, problematic. To take your example, if an "error" is a subjective measure, it is predictable that managers will define errors down to make themselves look better, so everyone will have a reduced error rate for the exact same performance. But a new manager might define it up, and then down, to show how they "improved" the same exact output.

Comment: It would be preferable to have a target of no critical errors (define critical). Or to have an improving error rate. And even better, this stuff should be targets for annual performance appraisal, not part of a job description.

Comment: KPI's involve a target that can not only be not quite met but can also be exceeded. You use it to measure whehter you are doing worse or better than the KPI target. I don't see how "error free" can be exceeded. Therefore, even if intended as a KPI it is flawed. A better KPI would be to measure the number of faults, test reports submitted against code you have written that resulted in actual code changes, etc.

Answer (score 4):

If it is a job description, then I wouldn't worry too much about it since working towards error free code is part of a typical programmer's job (even if we can never achieve it).

However, as a KPI it is too far reaching, but don't blame the person who suggested it if they aren't programmers. Just explain that that statement sets a goal that might be undesirable for the organization. That is, "error free" is an extremely high standard for software that would cost a fortune to actually deliver. Explain that a well run software project requires decisions to be made about whether each defect is worth spending valuable developer time on.

**Here's an example that makes the point nicely.**
A programmer discovers that our software has a "year 3000" bug and will cease to function after Dec 31,2999. It will take 6-8 months to fix the problem. Based on the KPI is encouraged to take on this project despite having no real value to the company.

Okay, so that example is a little extreme, but in any software project there will be literally dozens of little defects discovered that similarly don't generate the ROI required to fix them. If the KPI was instead intended to imply that the programmer never introduce the defect in the first place, does it seem reasonable for ANY employee to be held to the standard of never making a mistake in the performance of their job?

Comment: It seems unlikely that you'd have a KPI which covered "fixing defects which have been deemed by management not to be a problem, and not to need fixing."

Comment: @Carson - not in some big companies I know of. Silly goals is part of their way of doing business.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly this just sounds like a way for them to "cover all the bases", and is clearly not recommended and is likely to just engender disillusionment in the developers.

However having said that, this really only matters once you see what they do with that text during the review period. So don't overreact too quickly - there might still be sanity at the end of the tunnel.

Comment: Given my current work environment, I'd be very suspicious of how they'd apply that wording.

Answer (score 3):

## No

Not only is it not appropriate, it is *ludicrous*

Testing can only prove the existence of errors, not their absence, so every program written under this engagement would have to include a rigorous proof of correctness...**and** 100% test coverage

> "Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it." -- D. Knuth

Comment: KPIs are a measurement of success and progress towards a goal. They're not a binary toggle "error-free code = success, one single error = failure, you're fired!"

Comment: @Carson: "error-free" is not a KPI, it's a fantasy.

Comment: Sounds to me like a stitch-up. Put in something silly in the JD then whenever an excuse is needed the person can be fired because they are not performing as the JD requires.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it is every programmer's job, and responsibility, to write code that is error free.  That's a perfectly reasonable expectation.  How can you be a professional programmer if you release code that doesn't work?  How can you consider yourself to be a professional programmer if you release code that you don't *know* works?

If you hire a painter you expect him to do his job well.  You expect the result of his work to be error free.  If there are errors, you expect him to take responsibility for those errors and fix them free of charge.  What's more, if the errors cost you money, you expect him to reimburse you.  Why do you have these expectations?  Because the painter is a professional.

Programmers love to blame everyone else for their errors.  "My program has bugs because of the requirements, or because of the schedule, or because the Moon is in the 8th house"  But there's really no one else to blame.  If your program has errors, *you* put them there.

Our profession will never *be* a profession until programmers realize that the buck stops with them.  That *they* are responsible for the quality of their programs.

Do you know why companies created Software QA departments?  Because programmers weren't doing their jobs!  Programmers were releasing so much crap that companies had to form whole new departments to check up on them.

How long is the bug list?  It is professional to have thousands of bugs in the bug database?  Quite clearly it's not.  It's a reflection of bad behavior, poor discipline, and, frankly, dishonor.

We will never be a profession until we realize that is it our job to make sure that QA finds nothing.

Comment: +1, but I'd like to think of error free as a personal goal rather than reality. We should all go for it but unless given endless resources we won't get there, at least not given how we develop software now.

Comment: I could not agree more strongly with Uncle Bob's sentiments. It's very much a question of professionalism.

Comment: This position is complicated slightly by the fact that my management is *absolutely clear* that they would prefer me to give them buggy software now, rather than correct software later. I do not think i am alone in being in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

"Error-free" as in "perfect?" As in "written by God and the angels, not humans?" (we're speaking here of program-logic and maybe hardware-logic errors)

I can't say truthfully about even one single line of code that it is without error. That's because us humans, well, we can't prove no negative hypotheses!

The best I can say is that the *probability* of an error is a number between 0 and 1. I reach that number by way of well- or ill-defined and well- or ill-understood software development and testing principles; by a count of the source software lines in question; by an understanding of how well or poorly I candidate, poor mutt, applies those principles in producing those lines of code; and more.

And I can express ***that*** understanding only as a probability. So the term "logic-error-free" means close to nothing.

If I saw an ad for a software engineer who produced "error-free" code I'd either apply right away or I'd run right away: the company hasn't thought much about how it develops, tests, and delivers its software. So it'll be either a great opportunity or an endless nightmare.

Of any software, though, I can easily -- and must -- say I expect code that has no errors that fall *outside* that sucky, murky, logic-ey stuff: code that compiles and links without errors or warnings; that is "valid html" or "valid css"; JavaScript (say) that generates no unexplained error messages or browser faults. That part I can measure straightforwardly and mark in black and white on a graph.

That part's easy as pie. Anybody can do ***that***.

Hey, good luck in your search :-)

Answer (score 1):

Am I being stupid, or does "error" not mean "fatal compiler message amounting to non-compilable code"?

By that definition, it's a very reasonable requirement...

Comment: True. Having misaligned text on a page footer might be an error but it is certainly not in the same class of error as something that prevents a page to fail to load and spits runtime errors back to the user.

Comment: In web development, "error" could mean many things.  Displaying the wrong prices for all your products could be considered a major error, but it wouldn't necessarily prevent anything from running, and it may not report any problems in the server logs.

Comment: In the four years since writing this comment, I've done a hell of a lot more web development and totally agree - unusually though, I'm going to stand by my answer from 4 years ago and say that the point I was trying to make is that the definition of "error" is arbitrary, and for (very) select definitions it *is* a reasonable requirement.